# How to make a template string newlines to be collapsed?

Tags: javascript, templates

I use template strings to create reusable html snippets in my webapp:

```
const menuItem = `<li>
                      <a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>`
```

Though I found a problem with newlines that are kept literally so "Home" label has a visually visible space before it on the page. It happens because the string contains newlines where they are in the `menuItem` constant value declared.

How do I make these html snippets free of newlines and extra spaces where they are in the editor? Is the only way to to pass this string through a cleanup function or is there a more elegant automatic way to keep it clean?

Comment: Remove the new lines and whitespace in the string? The indentation will be kept in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove new lines
In your case

```
const menuItem = `<li>
                      <a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>`.replace(/^\s+/mg, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to improve readability in your Editor i think you should not use Javascript Template Strings. Instead use something like:

```
let menuItem = '<li>' +
                  '<a href="#">Home</a>' +
               '</li>'
```

Not exactly what you asked for, but if you have to conditionally concatenate the string you should probably do something like that and do not care about formatting:

```
const menuItem = []
menuItem.push('<li>')
menuItem.push('<a href="#">Home</a>')
if(moreMenuItems) {
  menuItem.push('<a href="#">Contact</a>')
}
menuItem.push('</li>')
menuItem.join('')
```

An alternative would be to implement a custom tagged template string function which takes your string and removes all unnecessary newlines and spaces:

```
function html(strings, ...values) {
  // Parse html snippet and remove unnecessary spaces and newlines
  return strings;
}

html`<li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
     </li>`;
```

Do not just search and replace for all newlines and spaces and remove them, because it is not safe within html tags.